# How to I pass hardcoded SQL queries into a JdbcBatchItemWriter?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch

Right now I have this:

```
<bean id="hardcodedQuery" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                DELETE from GENERIC_TABLE
                WHERE id = 999
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>       
</bean>
```

But I keep getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, saying that my SQL query is paramaterized. I know they want me to put some reference to the reader and have :randomVariable in the command, but I adamantly oppose this apparent requirement. Am I mistaken and is there a workaround? Or do I have to use a completely different class for my bean?

This is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Using SQL statement with '?' placeholders requires an ItemPreparedStatementSetter
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't have any parameters in your query, there is no need to define an itemSqlParameterSourceProvider. The itemSqlParamaterSourceProvider is looking for "named-parameters". I assume it raises the exception you received because it doesn't find any "named-parameters". Simply remove this property and try again.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding! Unfortunately I have already and after your comment tried again, but it does not solve the issue. I have created a somewhat more complicated workaround but so far it works fine, albeit with a few design quirks that I might not like.

It involves creating a custom bean with a custom class in the java packages.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this class isn't meant for what you're trying to do.  The `ItemWriter` contract assumes item based processing which would mean that you need to parameterize the SQL for each item.  If you want to run just a delete statement, use a `Tasklet` implementation that uses the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing and it worked. Thanks!